# How can I update my test web app with my bitbucket git repo automatically?

Tags: linux, git, apache, bitbucket

I Have a PHP application that runs on Apache on Linux. I have the code in Bitbucket/Git. Right now I clone the repo locally on my Windows laptop and edit the code with my IDE. I use WinSCP to push the code up to the Linux server where I just browse it to see the changes. I want to set up a test version (which I already have a Virtual Host/URL through Apache for) that gets automatically updated once I commit/push to my Bitbucket/Git repo. I have read another post about how to automatically set up a production environment with a git post-commit hook (others say to use a post-receive hook as it is server side). But I am getting confused as to what the instructions refer to as "server". This article is pretty much what I want: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks. But I get lost when it gets to the git-dir. My repo is in Bitucket and obviously not on the same server. Others have said to use Jenkins and all that stuff. But I don't have that luxury. Is there a way to do this by clongin the repo on my web server somewhere or at least creating a directory and git init in it. Then writing a post-receive web hook to pull the code down to my web server folder I have mapped the alias to each and every time there is a push from anyone to the to repo? Or am I making this too hard?